How to keep the core data updated in app and extensions
I'm using core data in app, widget extension and intent, but I found the data is not updated between targets. such as
I added a new record in app, the widget is not updated unless remove the widget and re-add it.
I added a new record in intent, the data in app is not updated unless I run the app again.
I have set container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true but it doesn't work.
So how can I make the data is updated no matter it is modified any targets.
